# Changing text font style

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change font family of the text "Processing".Below is the code:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="Processing...";
```

Comment: Gosh man.. i dont know. How about typing "javascript change font family" in google and clicking the first result ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      document.getElementById("txthint").style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and how to change the font size?

Comment: var txt = document.getElementById("txthint");
txt.style.fontSize = "25px";

Comment: Js is case sensitive so check if it is written as fontSize and not fontsize

Comment: var txt = document.getElementById("txthint");
txt.style.fontSize = "25px";
txt.innerHTML = "Processing...";

Comment: document.getElementById("txtHint").style.fontSize = "25";

Comment: i have given like this document.getElementById("txtHint").style.fontSize = "25"; But it's not working

Comment: It is 25px not just 25 document.getElementById("txtHint").style.fontSize = "25px";

Comment: Did this work?  `document.getElementById("txtHint").style.fontSize = "25px";`

Comment: pff.. stop feeding the question-troll.. The guy could have looked up his questions in a matter of seconds on google without having to bother anyone for it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").style.fontFamily = 'sans-serif';
```

Replace the `sans-serif` string with the font family of your choice.

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks for the help and how to change the font size?